Odd semiprimes of the form $(4k + 1)$
Let $N=p_1p_2$ be an odd semiprime of the form $(4k + 1)$.
Our goal is to find the exact value of ($p_1$ mod $4$).
If $N$ is difficult to factorize, do you have any other methods?

Have you tried a few examples? You don't need ones where $N$ is "difficult to factorize".

I have tried some semiprimes.
One of them is N=190340219499673906205121099983114322990720658444821845877126022044807359328206017174203063370697.
Because the question is related to mod 4, the answer is in {0, 1, 2, 3}.
Since N is odd, I can remove 0 and 2 and obtain {1,3}.
Then I do not know how to make a good guess between 1 and 3.
I know factorization is a way, but in practice the time is too limited to factorize N.
By the way, in this case, the correct answer is 1.

Like the factor of any odd integer, $p_1$ is odd so $,p_1\equiv \pm1\pmod{!4},,$ and we can't tell which case holds here without factoring (or further data). Note $,p_1p_2\equiv 1\Rightarrow p_2\equiv p_1.,$ As hinted above, there is no need to look at large integers to understand this. $\ \ $
